# PowerShell: Filtering an array by another [filter] array if any part of the text matches.

Tags: powershell

Okay, I'm still fairly new to PowerShell.

I've written a piece of code **that works**, but it smells entirely wrong.  What is the right way to write this from a PowerShell standpoint?

```
$filters = @("*a*","*b*")
$data = @("c/a","c/b","c/a/d","e","a","e/f")
$desiredResults = @("e","e/f")

Write-Host "Filters" -ForegroundColor Yellow
$filters 
Write-Host "Data" -ForegroundColor Yellow
$data

$results = @()

foreach ($d in $data)
{
    [bool] $skip = $false
    foreach ($filter in $filters)
    {
        if ($d -like $filter)
        {
            $skip = $true
        }
    }

    if ($skip -eq $false)
    {
        $results += $d
    }
}

Write-Host "Desired Results" -ForegroundColor Yellow
$desiredResults
Write-Host "Results" -ForegroundColor Yellow
$results
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do like this

```
$filters = @("a","b")
$data = @("c/a","c/b","c/a/d","e","a","e/f")
$desiredResults = @("e","e/f")

$data | Select-String -Pattern $filters -NotMatch
```

Comment: i like this solution, gj!

Comment: Exactly what I needed for this issue.  Clean and easy to read.

Answer (score 2):

The right way? I don't know that there is a right way. I can give you what I consider a better way using RegEx:

```
$filters = @("a","b")
$data = @("c/a","c/b","c/a/d","e","a","e/f")
$desiredResults = @("e","e/f")

$RegExFilter = ($Filters|%{[regex]::escape($_)}) -join '|'

$Results = $data | Where{$_ -notmatch $RegExFilter}

Write-Host "Desired Results" -ForegroundColor Yellow
$desiredResults
Write-Host "Results" -ForegroundColor Yellow
$results
```

This basically takes each element of the `$filters` array, performs a regex escape on it to escape any special characters, and then joins all of those results with a pipe character. So in the example given `$RegExFilter` equals `a|b`. Then it filters `$data` against anything that matches that pattern.

Comment: I like this one as well.  The reusable aspect is awesome.   I have to go with the Select-String option though just because it is easier to read at a glance.  Definitely going to save this snippet as well.

Answer (score 1):

I frequently have problems with double pipelines so I switch one to ForEach.
Here is a one-liner.

```
$filters = @("*a*","*b*")
$data = @("c/a","c/b","c/a/d","e","a","e/f")

ForEach ($Item in $data) { If ( !($filters | Where-Object {$Item -like $_})) { $Item } }
```

Answer (score 0):

The only real problem here - is you have to compare string to and array of strings, which I don't think powershell can do elegantly (but I might be wrong), so I've done this:

```
foreach ($d in $data)
{
    if ($d -notlike $filters[0] -and $d -notlike $filters[1])
    {
        $results += $d
    }
}
```

I assume the syntaxis is clean enough and doesn't need any explanation. if it needs explanation, tell me in comments.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$data | %{$val=$_; $Nb=($filters | where {$val -like $_}).Count ; if ($Nb -eq 0) {$val} }
```

Comment: This one doesn't match my expected results.  It only filters out one value ("a").

Comment: Strange it work on my pc. What is your PowerShell version?